# How to scan AWS DynamoDB with wild card in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I use aws-sdk in nodejs, And I should scan database with wildcard.

I tried this with [aws developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html):

```js
var params = {
    TableName: RecipeTable,
    FilterExpression: "#recipe = :recipe",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#recipe": "recipe",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":recipe": request.params.recipe,
    }
};
```

I can't reach the answer.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: In the guide they use `KeyConditionExpression` instead of `FilterExpression`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Molda In query, they use `KeyConditionExpresion`. But in scan, they use `FilterExpression`. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: Using `contains` keyword.

```js
app.get('/recipe/:recipe', (request, response) => {
    var params = {
        TableName: RecipeTable,
        FilterExpression: "contains(#recipe, :recipe)", // Here!
        ExpressionAttributeNames:{
              "#recipe": "ingredients"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":recipe": request.params.recipe
        }
    };

    result = [];
    docClient.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            data.Items.forEach((itemdata) => {
                result.push(itemdata);
            });

            if(typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
                params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                docClient.scan(params, onScan);
            } else {
                response.send(JSON.stringify({"result" : result}));
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I have referenced [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html#dynamodb-example-table-query-scan-scanning).

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a scan you will do often? how large is the dataset you are scanning? I am asking as over time this could get really expensive cost and performance-wise.

Comment: @Kirk About 100,000 rows (14.4MB). Is there any good choices instead of that code?

Comment: Well, you never say what it is you are trying to do, so it is difficult to say if there is a better way. Just know that a scan can be expensive if you do it often and the data set is large. If you are using a scan often, you might want to reevaluate your data model.